# Исключить обфускацию для части кода

Tags: android, gradle, обфускация, proguard

В своём приложении я ставлю minifyEnabled true, всё хорошо, но сейчас необходимо использовать библиотеку из гитхаба, но эта библиотека не должна быть обфусцирована, иначе NoSuchMethodException.

Возможно ли не обфусцировать несколько классов в моём приложении?
Что писать в proguard или что читать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы исключить какой-то класс можно написать например это:

```
-keep class com.google.** {*;}
```

где `**` означает любую дальнейшую цепочку.